# Can't install Docker : Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 15063 to run

Tags: docker, installation

I'm new in docker using. I'm using window Home 10, version 1909, OS build 18363.720 now.

I had an issue when installing Docker.
Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 15063 to run.
I have tried to update window and install again but it does still not work!

[image: Error window Image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you using Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise? It specifically asks you for Windows 10 *Pro* or *Enterprise*. If you are using Windows 10 Home, the build version doesn't matter, you cannot use Docker Desktop.

But there is a way to run Docker on Windows 10 Home using Virtual Box instead of Hyper V: https://www.sitepoint.com/docker-windows-10-home

**Update: *Windows 10 Home from build 2004 and above now supports Docker out of the box* and it's not necessary to follow any of the steps in the guide linked above.**

You can try to update your copy of Windows through `Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update`.

If this still doesn't update to build version 2004, or if you can't update via the built-in updater, the update can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10.

By clicking on the button marked with a red line you will start downloading an executable file (.exe) that can be executed to install the update manually:

[image: screenshot with highlighted download button]

Comment: actually i use window Home! I dont't  know about the sys. requirement, Thank you, Max.

Comment: you can run Docker on Windows Home though, see the link in my updated answer. Also don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if your problem is solved

Comment: Seems not to work with the October 2020 update.

Comment: Why should I update something to install a program that already worked on an older version. This is a violation of my freedom!

Answer (score 15):

Edit Windows Version in Registry

1.Press Windows + R and write regedit
2. In the Registry Editor, go to \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
3. Right-click on EditionID and Click Modify
4. Change Value Data to Professional
5. Press OK

Edit Windows CurrentBuild (set 18363) and  CurrentBuildNumber (set 18363) with the same way.

Injoy Docker

Comment: Amazing. Just amazing!! Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Much needed instruction!

Comment: I had Win10 Pro, build 19043, but updating to 19044 kept failing. Docker required 19044 to be installed. Editing the number in the registry as explained above worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

Here is an easy-fix that worked for me.

Using `Settings  > Update & Security   > Windows Update` alone was NOT enough to do the right `update` to  `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.330]` that I needed.

But then, this worked:

Downloaded & executed `Windows10Upgrade9252.exe` from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

That was it.

Answer (score 3):

Docker Desktop will now work on Windows 10 Home for version 2004
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install-windows-home/

Unfortunately I think 2004 is only available at this time on the **Window Insider Program**, which requires you to set your diagnostic data to full which includes sending *'info about websites you browse and how you  use apps and features'*

I think I will be following the advice @Max has given for now.

Answer (score 2):

Edit Windows Version in Registry

1. Press `Windows + R` and write `regedit`
2. In the Registry Editor, go to
   `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
3. Right-click on `EditionID` and click `Modify`
4. Change `Value Data` to `Professional`
5. Press `OK`

Edit Windows CurrentBuild (set 18363) and CurrentBuildNumber (set 18363) with the same way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34445398)

Comment: It's allready Professional :(

Comment: This was the best answer, actually!

Answer (score 1):

According to this 
https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-desktop-for-windows-home-is-here/
You need version 19040 ( a preview version ). Hope they will bring it to 2004 version ( release date May 2020)

Answer (score 0):

now in the docs section of docker (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/), windows home users link over to dockerhub to download the windows home version of docker here:
https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows/